# PHP-GDS Upsert overwritring nonspecified values

Tags: php, google-cloud-datastore

I have a keys only query - something like this -

$Sub = $obj_store->fetchOne("SELECT **key** WHERE **key** HAS ANCESTOR KEY(Subscribe, $key)");

I set a value on one of the fields

$Sub->active = TRUE;

then do an upsert

$obj_store->upsert($Sub);

The one value is updated, but the other existing columns are erased. If I do a select * the values are not erased.

I need to avoid a full record read for billing.

How can I update a field in a record and avoid deleting all the others? I'm using the php-gds wrapper for cloud-datastore.

the desire would a query like the following
update subscribe set active = TRUE where keyid = 1234

Answer (score 1):

Writes to Cloud Datastore assume that you are sending in a "whole" entity. You cannot update specific properties of an entity like you can in a relational database. Like you found out, correct way to update an entity is to first read the whole entity from the Datastore, then change one or more properties and then save.